# Android - withdraw an animation

Tags: android

I want my random chosen image to reset after it has been animated, so another randomly choosen image is at the origin point and the old one is deleted. How do I get back to the part where the image is set from the animation?

```
Random rand = new Random();
                    int imag = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;

                    switch (imag)
                        {
                        case 1:
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);

                            break;

                        case 2:
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);

                            break;

                        case 3:
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.c);

                            break;

                        case 4:
                            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.d);

                            break;
                            }                   

        }        


        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
        {

            final ViewPropertyAnimator animator = imageView.animate();
            switch (touchevent.getAction())
            {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                {
                    x1 = touchevent.getX();
                    y1 = touchevent.getY();
                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    x2 = touchevent.getX();
                    y2 = touchevent.getY();



                    if (x1 < x2 && (x2-x1)>=(y1-y2) && (x2-x1)>=(y2-y1))
                    {

                        animator.translationX(imageView.getWidth()*2) 
                                .setDuration(180) //it's optional                               
                                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);                                             
                                    }
                                })

                                .start();
                    }
                   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
int getMyRandomResId() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int imag = rand.nextInt(4);

    switch (imag) {
        case 0:
            return R.drawable.a;
        break;
        case 1:
            return R.drawable.b;
        break;
        case 2:
            return R.drawable.c;
        break;
        default:
            return R.drawable.d;
    }
}

private boolean animationRunning = false;

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent)
{
    final ViewPropertyAnimator animator = imageView.animate();
    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            x1 = touchevent.getX();
            y1 = touchevent.getY();
            break;
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            x2 = touchevent.getX();
            y2 = touchevent.getY();

            if (!animationRunning) {
                if (x1 > x2 && (x1 - x2) >= (y1 - y2) && (x1 - x2) >= (y2 - y1)) {
                    animationRunning = true;
                    animator.translationX(-imageView.getWidth() * 2)
                            .setDuration(180)
                            .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                                    imageView.setTranslationX(0);
                                    imageView.setImageResource(getMyRandomResId());
                                    animationRunning = false;
                                }
                            })
                            .start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the code for more information. After animating my image it should set back at origin point and choose a new rendom image

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want exactly - there might be a jump at the end so maybe an extra entrance animation is needed.

Comment: I tried your code, but I don't know what your `public void performAnimation()` method is for, because it is not called I think so I left it out. The other part of your code with the `getMyRandomResId()` sounds very logical to me, but if I set it up I get a blank screen, what could be the reason for that?

Comment: You are right about performAnimation() (it's just a leftover) ;)  - I deleted it. As for the blank screen - Is there a chance your translation is not 0 when you start the animation? I was assuming that 0 is the original position. But if this assumption is wrong, a blank screen is a definite possibility. BTW, which animator class are you using?

Comment: Okay, so it works in principle. The image resets to its initial point, but the outcome of this is that there isn't an image when the activity is startet, first when an animation is done. The second problem is that the image is 'blinking': it's switches very fast between the images when the gesture is done, why doesn't one picture stay until the animation is over? And i'm implementing the OnGestureListener, no extra class

Comment: You need to make sure that you don't call start the animation before the previous one ends - you can add a variable and set it to true before you start and false in onAnimationEnd().  As for the activity start, call imageView.setImageResource(getMyRandomResId()); in onCreate().

Comment: Is that variable a condition for the if statement to start?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128873/discussion-between-doron-yakovlev-golani-and-joe-s).